# R: cumulative sum with conditions

Tags: r, cumsum

Let's say  I need to take cumulative sum of a vector

```
  set.seed(123)

  x <- sample(-5:5, 15,replace = T)
  x
  -2  3 -1  4  5 -5  0  4  1  0  5 -1  2  1 -4
```

x are values for 15 days with first value belonging to day 1

I can take cumsum of x as

```
   cumsum(x)

   -2  1  0  4  9  4  4  8  9  9 14 13 15 16 12
```

However, the condition I want to impose is that at any given day, cumsum cannot exceed 10 or go negative. If for a day, it exceeds 10, make it 10 or if it is less than zero, make it zero.

I did this:

```
  ifelse(10 + cumsum(x) < 0, 0, ifelse(10 + cumsum(x) > 10, 10,cumsum(x)))

  -2 10  0 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

This does not give me the right answer since my first value is negative and values which are less than 10 are converted into 10. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

```
  if this is x,           -2,3,-1,4,5,-5,0,4,1,0,5,-1,2,1,-4
  then the calculation is: 8 (10 - 2= 8)
                           10 (8 + 3 = 11, converted into 10)
                           9 (10 - 1 = 9)
                          10 (9 + 4 = 13, converted into 10)
                          10 (10 + 5 = 15, converted into 10)
                           5 (10 - 5 = 5)
                           5 (5 + 0 = 5)
                           9 (5 + 4 = 9)
                          10 (9 + 1 = 10)
                          10 (10 + 0 = 10)
                          10 (10 + 5 = 15, converted into 10)
                           9 (10 - 1 = 9)
                          10 (9 + 2 = 11, converted into 10)
                          10 (10 + 1 = 11, converted into 10)
                          6 (10 -4 = 6)
```

Final answer should be:

```
                   8, 10, 9, 10, 10, 5,5,9,10,10,10,9,10,10,6
```

Comment: What would be the right answer (the desired result)?

Comment: You can do it separately.
    `a <- cumsum(x); 
    a[a > 10 | a < 0] = 10`

Comment: I have edited the question to show final answer